# Submit calls function two times

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When I submit the form with Enter, it works without any problems. I can successfully log in. When I submit the form with a button, it logs in successfully on Firefox, but not on Chrome. The problem is, it repeats the function twice and sends a different hashed password. How can I make it to work on Chrome too?

**Button:**

```
<div id="submit" name="submit" value="login" class="ui fluid large pink submit button" onclick="submitForm();">Login</div>
```

**Form:**

```
<form id="form" autocomplete="off" class="ui large form" id = "form" name="form" method="post" action="php/verify.php" onsubmit="submitForm();">
```

I added `onsubmit="submitForm();"` to form, to call the function even when I submit the form with `Enter`.

**Javascript function:**

```
function submitForm(){
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
    var hash = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT", {numRounds: 1});
    hash.update(pwd.value);
    var hash = hash.getHash("HEX");
    var password = document.createElement("input");
    password.name="password";
    password.type="hidden";
    password.id = "password";
    password.value = hash;
    alert(password.value);
    form.appendChild(password);
    form.submit();
    pwd.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your onsubmit handler, you're submitting the form:

```
 form.submit();
```

If you do that, the handler has to return false, which means you need

```
<form ... onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
```

Otherwise you will submit the form manually, then the browser will submit it a second time, since onsubmit didn't return false;

Comment: Can you explain it why did my code work in Firefox, but not in Chrome?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that since submitting a form means the browser will navigate to a new resource, what happened is you told the browser to load another page twice, in quick succession. Firefox probably cancels the first request as soon as the second happens, while Chrome devs chose to process both.

Answer (score 1):

You have two submits:

```
onsubmit="submitForm();" and onclick="submitForm();"
```

remove one of them

Comment: Well if I remove one of them, I wouldn't be able to submit with both Enter and Button.

Comment: He is wrong; having multiple elements that call a function doesn't necessarily mean the function is called multiple times.

Comment: But there is no need for two submits when what is needed can be done using just one.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible causes:

1- You have two handlers installed: `onSubmit` and `onClick`. Instead, leave the `onSubmit` handler and use a button with `submit` type:

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm()">
  <input type="submit"> <!-- this is equivalent to pressing enter -->
  <button type="submit"></button> <!-- also equivalent -->
</form>
```

2- If you're going to manually `submit` the form in the event handler, you should stop the default behavior from taking place, which could account for the 2nd (unprocessed) submit:

```
function submitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onsubmit="submitForm();` from the `<form>` tag and create the `<input type="submit" onclick="submitForm();>` inside the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input control (type=submit) instead of a div for the login button.
That is something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="ui fluid large pink submit button"/>
```

So the onsubmit call will be enough.